# Updating a PictureBox in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm currently writing an application to play Chess over a network. However I'm running into a small issue.

```
TableLayoutPanels cells;
cells = GetBoard();
this.Controls.Add(cells);

 private TableLayoutPanel GetBoard()
    {
        TableLayoutPanel b = new TableLayoutPanel();
        b.ColumnCount = 8;
        b.RowCount = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.ColumnCount; i++) { b.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, Cell.CellSize.Width)); }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.RowCount; i++) { b.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, Cell.CellSize.Height)); }
        for (int row = 0; row < b.RowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < b.ColumnCount; col++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell(row, col);
                cell.Click += new EventHandler(this.cell_Click); //Added an event handler
                b.Controls.Add(cell, col, row);
            }
        }
        b.Padding = new Padding(0);
        b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(b.ColumnCount * Cell.CellSize.Width, b.RowCount * Cell.CellSize.Height);

        return b; //Returns the whole table
    }
```

GetBoard initializes a board of 8 by 8 of PictureBoxes. I have a mouse event handler to switch the images of the PictureBoxes when the user clicks two of them.

```
private void cell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Cell currentClickedCell = (Cell) sender; 
   currentClickedCell.Image = prevClickedCell.Image; //Switch the two images
   prevClickedCell = null; //Set the previously clicked cell's image to blank
}
```

The information will then be send over the network, via ints (cast into an enum using a switch statement).

However, I don't know how to update the information once I get a response from the server (two ints). I'll phrase this the best I can: "Is there a way to get the "object sender" of the two cells" to switch the images?

Comment: An enum doesn't strike me as a great way to encode a chess piece position.  You want to encode "e2 to e4".  You can number the positions from 0 to 63, easily fits in a byte, but you'd never use an enum for that.  Did you think this through?

Comment: Hi Hans, the person in charge of the logic for chess wanted it to be an enum, so I only follow what he said.

Answer (score 0):

This code will "swap" the current image with the last image:

```
private void cell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Cell currentClickedCell = (Cell)sender;
  if (prevClickedCell != null) {
    Image img = currentClickedCell.Image;
    currentClickedCell.Image = prevClickedCell.Image;
    prevClickedCell.Image = img;
  }
  prevClickedCell = currentClickedCell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The team decided to create another array of Cells that would point to the cells on the board. This allowed for the GUI to change without any human interaction. I apologize for the confusing wording...